# V8 embedding: null `this` from method inside class inheriting from one created using Function::New

Tags: v8, embedded-v8

I am trying to embed V8 with a custom class.  It is made to be extended and used in JS.

When accessing `this` in a method other than the constructor, it is `null`.  It should be able to persist data for that instance of the class.

Am I missing something?

JavaScript

```js
import { Behavior } from '@giz/ecs';

class A extends Behavior {
  constructor(a) {
    super(a);

    this.a = 10;

    print(this); // this works
  }

  update() {
    print(this); // null
  }
}

A;
```

How I am creating `Behavior`

```cpp
    Local<Module> ecsModule = Module::CreateSyntheticModule(
        isolate,
        String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "@giz/ecs").ToLocalChecked(),
        {String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Behavior").ToLocalChecked()},
        [](Local<Context> context, Local<Module> module) -> MaybeLocal<Value>
        {
            auto isolate = context->GetIsolate();
            // behavior constructor right now is an empty function
            auto behavior = Function::New(context, behaviorConstructor).ToLocalChecked();

            module->SetSyntheticModuleExport(
                String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Behavior").ToLocalChecked(),
                behavior);

            return MaybeLocal<Value>(True(isolate));
        });
    ecsModule->InstantiateModule(context, ScriptingSystem::moduleResolutionCallback);

    // store the module for later use
    Global<Module> *globalModule = new Global<Module>();
    globalModule->Reset(isolate, ecsModule);
    modules["@giz/ecs"] = globalModule;
```

Instantiating the class and calling the update function

```cpp
    v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
    // globalContext is a v8::Global<v8::Context> with the print function created
    v8::Local<Context> context = Local<Context>::New(isolate, globalContext);
    Context::Scope contextScope(context);

    // ...
    // create script origin, script source, instantiate module, ..
    // ...

    Local<Value> returnValue = module->Evaluate(context).ToLocalChecked();
    Local<Object> returnedBehavior = returnValue->ToObject(context).ToLocalChecked();

    Local<Value> arguments[1];
    arguments[0] = wrapEntity(*behavior->entity);

    // creates an instance of the behavior
    auto instance = returnedBehavior->CallAsConstructor(context, 1, arguments)
                        .ToLocalChecked()
                        ->ToObject(context)
                        .ToLocalChecked();

    // calls the update function
    instance->Get(context, String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "update").ToLocalChecked())
        .ToLocalChecked()
        ->ToObject(context)
        .ToLocalChecked()
        ->CallAsFunction(context, Null(isolate), 0, nullptr);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the last line:

> `->CallAsFunction(context, Null(isolate), 0, nullptr);`

The second argument to `CallAsFunction` is the "receiver", which is the thing that will be accessible as `this` inside the called function: since you pass `Null(isolate)` there, `this` will be `null`. Try passing `instance` instead.
(Essentially, your current code is doing the equivalent of `let instance = new A(); instance.update.call(null);`.)

---

Side note: please be aware that `ToLocalChecked` will crash your process if the previous operation threw an exception. The requirement to convert `MaybeLocal`s to `Local`s explicitly has been introduced for the purpose of pointing out all the places where C++ code should check for exceptions, and handle them somehow. Only in the rare cases where you can guarantee that an operation won't throw (such as allocating a short string), using `ToLocalChecked` is safe. Examples that will currently crash your process:

- `A`'s constructor throws
- `A`'s constructor returns `null`
- `A`'s constructor installs a getter for `update` that throws
- `A`'s constructor installs a getter for `update` that returns `null`

A common pattern is:

```cpp
Local<...> value;
if (!FunctionThatReturnsMaybeLocal(...).ToLocal(&value)) {
  /* Handle error: show message, skip silently, ... */
  return;
}
// Now work with {value}.
```

(Yes, working with JavaScript from C++ is difficult.)